# Как транскрибируется на русский название "Mon pelerin"?

Tags: транскрипция

Возник вопрос по поводу названия [общества "Мон Пелерин"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_%C2%AB%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%9F%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%C2%BB). Насколько вообще адекватна такая транскрипция (встречались еще "Мон Пелерен", а также вариации с дефисами)?

Comment: Если вам дан (или будет дан) исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score -1):

По-английски это название читается примерно как [монт пелерин] (Mont Pelerin), по-французски — [мо пелерэ] (Mont Pèlerin). Можно сказать, что запись «Мон Пелерин» отражает французское произношение, но только первого слова; второе слово, очевидно, транслитерировано. Если это устоявшаяся традиция, то тут уже ничего не поделаешь — даже такая помесь из транскрипции с транслитерацией нормальна. (Вспомните Анри—Генри—Генриха.)